# Visual Studio's Python type inference seems to be going crazy?

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2015, type-inference

I have the following code, and its type is (not) being inferred in a very bizarre fashion.

What's confusing is that this is **not** just a typical failure of the engine to infer types, but rather it's exhibiting such strange behavior that I cannot even understand *where* or *what* the bug might be.

Can someone explain what is going on? Why do the **order**  and the **presence** of the statements that assign to `x`, `y`, and `z` affect the types of *each other*?

(For your convenience, I've added a suffix indicating the inferred type, so `z1__int` is inferred as `int`.)

```
def lmap1(func, items):
    return [func(item1) for item1 in items]

def tmap(f, items):
    return tuple(lmap1(f, items))

def a():
    f = lambda i: i
    items = [1]
    x1__unknown = tmap(f, items)[0]
    y1__unknown = tuple(lmap1(f, items))[0]
    z1__int     = tuple([f(item1) for item1 in items])[0]

def b():
    f = lambda i: i
    items = [1]
    y2__int     = tuple(lmap1(f, items))[0]
    x2__unknown = tmap(f, items)[0]
    z2__int     = tuple([f(item1) for item1 in items])[0]

def c():
    f = lambda i: i
    items       = [1]
    y3__unknown = tuple(lmap1(f, items))[0]
    x1__unknown = tmap(f, items)[0]
```

Comment: for `f`, use a full `def` function definition.  Just a hunch but the `lambda`s may be screwing things up. You shouldn't be using `lambdas` that way, anyways. They are suppose to be used for anonymous functions, and using a named lambda defeats the point. As an aside, there's a lot of reinventing the wheel here and needlessly inefficient code. Learn to use generator expressions and the `next` built-in.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You **do** realize this isn't production code I'm actually running, right? You know what [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) means? It's just a minimal example that exhibits the problem, not an example that I was seeking anyone's coding style opinions on...

Comment: Yeah, sure. That's why I said it as an aside. In any case, the `lambda` bit was an actual guess. Any luck when you changed that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Even if it had worked, it wouldn't have helped since it's not like I'm going to change the lambdas in my code to `def`s just to get the type inference working. But no, I just tried it and changing the `lambda`s to `def`s didn't change anything.